# I get different results with hd and hexdump, aren't they the same?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

When I run each command, I get the following output:

```js
root@ubuntu:~# hd test.txt 
00000000  31 32 33 34 35 36 0a                              |123456.|
00000007
root@ubuntu:~# hexdump test.txt 
0000000 3231 3433 3635 000a                    
0000007
```

But both commands are looking at the same location on the disk:

```js
root@ubuntu:~# which hd
/usr/bin/hd
root@ubuntu:~# ls -l /usr/bin/hd 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jul  6 03:13 /usr/bin/hd -> hexdump
```

Can anyone tell me why the results I get are different from each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is closely related to [this answer on Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17319/can-hd-and-od-replace-each-other).

"`hd` is a synonym for `hexdump -C`"

They are very similar, but you are actually calling very slightly different things with each command.

Comment: hd is linked to hexdump, so how does hexdump know the user use hd?

Comment: @peterzhang `hexdump` reads its `argv[0]` which tells it it's invoked as `hd` ([usually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051035/10765659)).